# Active SR latch output conditons

Tags: digital-logic

For the active high SR latch, is there anyway to predict which combination the outputs will be when S=0 and R=0?
For example,
Q = 1, Q'= 0

OR

Q = 0, Q' = 1
[image]

Comment: Draw a table with as rows R / S / Q and Q', and columns "current value" and "next value" and reason what happens.

Comment: You still need a starting value for the output....

Comment: Start with the one in the picture. Next, Q=0 and Q'=1.

Comment: I do understand how a SR latch works, i'm not the one asking... But, I may fail reading your mind. Maybe you mean: what is the value of Q and Q' at power up given S=0 and R=0? Clarifying helps more than calling names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TI [says](https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic/f/151/t/737715):

> Flip-flops, latches, and registers do not have a default state on power up.  The output is in an 'unknown' state until data is clocked through.
>
> This is because the underlying latch circuit used to store the output value is inherently unstable at startup.  It could become a HIGH or a LOW at the output, and the value is impossible to determine before it is measured.